# How to perform a operations with inputs' values with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Today I created a new site where people can calculate an average beetween some numbers. I have this HTML code:

```
<div id='content'>
   <h1>Calculator de medii cu teza</h1>

  <select>
    <option value='nr'>Cate note ai fara teza?</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='6'>6</option>
  </select>



  <input id='Note' placeholder='Scrie aici notele tale'/> <br/>
  <input id='Teza' placeholder='Scrie aici nota din teza'/> <br/>
  <input id='Run' onClick='calc()' type='button' value='Calculeaza'/>
  <input id='Rezultat' readOnly='true' style='font-style: italic; padding-left:-2px; !important' type='text' value='rezultatul va aprea aici'/>

  </div>
```

I want something which could calculate this ecuation:

(((Nota / nr) *3) + Teza) / 4

I am new here, so I really need help. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `\ `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your select element and Id property and give it a name "nrId"

```
<select id="nrId">
```

Run code below...

```
var noteVal = document.getElementById("Note").value;
var tezaVal = document.getElementById("Teza").value;

var selectObj = document.getElementById("nrId");
var selectVal = selectObj.options[selectObj.selectedIndex].value;

var result = (((noteval / selectVal) * 3) + tezaVal) / 4;
document.getElementById("Rezultat").value = result;
```

Comment: And how can I replace Rezultat's value with result?